# How to implement a NUnit test that checks for a state change in an object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm working on incorporating some unit tests into an old poker game and I ran into some trouble when trying to test for a state change.

The class diagram for the related classes looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXNY1.png).

This is the method (which is inside the class `CardSet`) that updates the state of all cards in the set:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets each of the card's Inplay properties to false. 
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetUsage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
           cardArray[i].Inplay = false;            
    }
```

The NUnit test that I'm trying to implement should check to see whether the `Inplay` property was indeed set to false.

My question is whether its possible to code this NUnit test?

**Edit:**

This question was originally regarding testing non-static methods but I realized (and as Lasse pointed out) that I was really trying to confirm for a change in state. Therefore, I've revised the question in an effort to aid future readers.

I've learned that it is possible to test for any effect and that you can inject dependencies to do so. My self-answer demonstrates this to some degree.

Comment: You can test any observable effect. If you can observe the change, either by being told via events or similar, or manually by checking each card afterwards, then yes, you can test this. The main issue to consider is dependencies, are you able to actually run the code so that you can observe it, or will it be waiting for players, UI events, etc?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. For some reason, I thought it wasn't possible to test non-static methods. I should mention that this is my first time experimenting with unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

If you can instantiate the CardSet class in a junit test you can test that ResetUsage() does what you expect. If you can observe what RunPokerSession does to a CardSet will depend on the design and structure of RunPokerSession, and that is not clear from you question. You will, most likely, want to inject a CarSet to the RunPokerSession and then observe the result. Can you do that with the current implementation?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do so. I will post my solution here.

Comment: Great! Good for you!

Answer (score 0):

With Lasse's and Jocke's help, I was able to think through the implementation. This is how I tested for the change.

```
    [Test]
    public void ResetUsage_ValidateInPlayReset_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        CardSet testDeck = new CardSet();

        testDeck.ResetUsage();

        bool result = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < testDeck.cardArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (testDeck.cardArray[i].Inplay)
            {
                result = false; 
                break;
            }               
        }

        Assert.That(result);
    }
```